# How do I list all tga files in a directory (non recursive) in Python?

Tags: python

How do I list all tga files in a directory (non recursive) in Python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are doing it based on file extension, you can do something like this:

```
import os
directory = "C:/"
extension = ".tga"
list_of_files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]
```

Obviously you can omit the lower() if you can garantee the case of the files. Also there is the excellent path.py (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py) module.

If you do not know the file extension you can use something like PIL (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to detect the file type by decoding the file.

Comment: I tried this and others, but somehow I got nothing. Tried different formats, on this dir: "C:/Documents and Settings/yunus/My Documents/My Received Files/"

Is there any problem with this?

Comment: If you:

    import os
    for file in os.listdir("C:/Documents and Settings/yunus/My Documents/My Received Files/"):
        print file

does it print anything?

Comment: Sorry, the comment system seems to have cluttered up my newlines, hope you can decypher that =)

Comment: Thanks Jotham. It was my fault. I was calling a different function. I also wonder if you can add the path, using your method since it's one liner?

Comment: Sure,

list_of_files = [os.path.join(directory, file) for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]

Comment: PIL is Python Imaging Library. It is worth mentioning how exactly do you use it to detect a file type.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian:  PIL autodetects the file type of opened images; ` from PIL import Image; i = Image.open('somefile'); print i.format `

Answer (score 14):

```
import glob, os
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(yourPath, "*.tga"))
   print(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following example uses `filter`, which offers an elegant solution as shown below:

```
import os
files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.tga'), os.listdir(DIR))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import os
>>> for file in [tga for tga in os.listdir(directory) if tga.endswith(".tga")]:
>>>     print file
```

Answer (score 0):

My Targa/Vista have often .vst and .tga, sometimes other extension:

```
import os
from glob import glob
import PIL

filenames = []
for filename in glob(os.path.join(dirname, "*.*")):
    try:
        img = PIL.Image(filename)
        if img.format == "TGA":
            filenames.append(filename)
    except IOError: // from PIL if not recognised
        pass
```